# How to use a class of one project in another project under the same solution?

Tags: c#

I have two projects of Web API and Windows Forms App under one solution.

The names are:

- Solution - CliendAddress
- Web API - ClientAddress
- WFA - ClientAddressWFA

[image]

In the ClientAddress project  there is a class called ServiceResponse. How can I use this ServiceResponse class in my project ClientAddressWFA?

From my ClientAddressWFA, I've already added the reference to ClientAddress 
[image]
[image]

However, when I am trying to add using ClientAddress.Models; (<---- This is where the ServiceResponse class is) in my ClientAddress.WFA project, I'm getting an error

[image]

Recording: https://screenrec.com/share/XTp0dwbI42

Comment: Have you restarted VS?

Comment: If your models are shared across multiple projects, you can break the models off into a class library - independent from your other projects. Then, import that class library into your projects. [edit - also yeah, try turning vs off and on again :)]

Comment: _"I'm getting an error"_ - _What_ error?

Comment: as a big suggestion, create a new Class Library project (ClientAddress.Services), and move there the ServiceResponse.
Add a reference to the new project in both the projects ClientAddress and ClientAddressWFA.

Comment: What does visual studio say when you hover over that `ClientAddress` as a suggestion to fix it? - much of the time it will give a good suggested resolution.

Comment: Added recording to the question

Comment: Wrong namespace in the using directive, the video shows you typed "ClientAddressWFA".  Best to pick unique names that don't resemble each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just this one source file then you can just add it to the other project "as link". Quick and dirty, but who cares. However, if you need more classes, then make a shared library project that would then be referenced by both projects. That's what shared libraries are for.

So, in project ClientAddressWFA try to add this one .cs file but instead of clicking "Add" click on small triangle next to "Add", and select "Add As Link".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes just restarting the visual studio and compiling again will work (Given that class you are referencing from another project is public and you have added project reference)